# How to copy array keys to another array, and replace values with empty array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, f. e.:

```
$arr = array(
    4 => 'some value 1',
    7 => 'some value 2',
    9 => 'some value 3',
    12 => 'some value 4',
    13 => 'some value 5',
    27 => 'some value 6',
    41 => 'some value 7'
)
```

I need to create another array, where values will be array, but the keys will be the same; like this:

```
$arr = array(
    4 => array(),
    7 => array(),
    9 => array(),
    12 => array(),
    13 => array(),
    27 => array(),
    41 => array()
)
```

Is there some build-in function in PHP for do that? `array_keys()` didn't help me:

```
var_dump(array_keys($arr));
```

Returned:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  int(1)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  int(3)
  [4]=>
  int(4)
  [5]=>
  int(5)
  [6]=>
  int(6)
}
```

Comment: *array_keys() didn't help me.* <- Show your code and where you are stuck

Comment: By the way, my solusion works faster than this, i think,because less function calls  :) https://eval.in/379770

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this . You can use **array_fill_keys()** for more info [follow this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php)

```
$arr = array(
    4 => 'some value 1',
    7 => 'some value 2',
    9 => 'some value 3',
    12 => 'some value 4',
    13 => 'some value 5',
    27 => 'some value 6',
    41 => 'some value 7'
);
$keys=array_keys($arr);

$filledArray=array_fill_keys($keys,array());
print_r($filledArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

Just [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) your [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) from the old array, with an [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)'ed array full of empty arrays.

```
<?php

    $newArray = array_combine(array_keys($arr), array_fill(0, count($arr), []));
    print_r($newArray);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [4] => Array ()  
    [7] => Array ()    
    [9] => Array ()    
    [12] => Array ()    
    [13] => Array ()    
    [27] => Array ()
    [41] => Array ()

)
```

Comment: Its enough to use this `array_fill_keys(array_keys($arr), array());`, but yes, this is also another and longer solution...

Comment: and this is  slower 40% :))))

Answer (score 1):

Change values to array saving keys:

```
$arr2 = array_map(function ($i){
    return array();
}, $arr);
```

result

```
Array
(
    [4] => Array ( )  
    [7] => Array ( )    
    [9] => Array ( )    
    [12] => Array ( )    
    [13] => Array ( )    
    [27] => Array ( )
    [41] => Array ( )

)
```

Comment: Thanks. Its enough to use this `array_fill_keys(array_keys($arr), array());`, but yes, this is also another solution...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $array[$key] = array('a','b','c');
}
```

Comment: Please never post code-only / "try this" answers on Stack Overflow.